# Cisco 2911 - problem with DHCP

Tags: cisco, dhcp, ios

i am configuring DHCP daemon on Cisco 2911.

At some point i assigned address 192.168.50.50 to one box (using MAC address 'relation').

When I wanted to saved config - I got warning, that address 192.168.50.50 is already in Pool, which sounds bit weird - it was first host which I started configuring.

I tried with following commands:

```
clear ip dhcp server statistics
clear ip dhcp conflict
```

but first one doesn't output anything (and show statistics shows that there are 2 addresses in pool), and second one throws "there is no conflicted ips" message.

How I can force/purge/clear/allow to bind 192.168.50.50 to this box?

Comment: Could you post a config snipet, with the relvent dhcp-related bit of the config.

Comment: Yes, tomorrow - today I have no access to the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the CLI depending on the IOS version running you need to exclude any statically defined addresses from your pool, other the router believes it can assign all addresses in the pool range to dhcp clients

ip dhcp excluded-address low-address [high-address]

or in your case

ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.50.50

[Cisco Documentation](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_0t/12_0t1/feature/guide/Easyip2.html#wp21020)